# Decode base64 encrypted string

Tags: c#, xml, zip, base64, unzip

This is probably a very localized question not useful for the rest of the community but hopefully someone can help me.

**What I know**

I have a base64 encoded ZIP, in a string, inside an XML element.

*The file looks like this:*

```
<Document>
   <Content vesion="1"><!-- BASE64 STRING ---></Content>
</Document>
```

**What I want to do**

Decode the string, and then unzip it.

**What I've tries so far (and failed)**

- Decoded the base64 string and put it in a file with a zip extension

  ```
  public string DecodeFrom64(string encodedData)
  {

      byte[] encodedDataAsBytes

          = System.Convert.FromBase64String(encodedData);

      string returnValue =

         System.Text.Encoding.Unicode.GetString(encodedDataAsBytes);

      return returnValue;

  }
  ```
- Tried to unzip the string with the function:

  ```
  public static string DecompressString(string compressedText)
  {
      byte[] gZipBuffer = Convert.FromBase64String(compressedText);
      using (var memoryStream = new MemoryStream())
      {
          int dataLength = BitConverter.ToInt32(gZipBuffer, 0);
          memoryStream.Write(gZipBuffer, 4, gZipBuffer.Length - 4);

          var buffer = new byte[dataLength];

          memoryStream.Position = 0;
          using (var gZipStream = new GZipStream(memoryStream, CompressionMode.Decompress))
          {
              gZipStream.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
          }

          return Encoding.UTF8.GetString(buffer);
      }
  }
  ```

**Got the error:**

> The magic number in GZip header is not correct. Make sure you are passing in a GZip stream...

- Tried to decompress the string with the function:

  ```
  public static string UnZipStr(string compressedText)
  {
      byte[] input = Convert.FromBase64String(compressedText);
      using (MemoryStream inputStream = new MemoryStream(input))
      {
          using (DeflateStream gzip =
            new DeflateStream(inputStream, CompressionMode.Decompress))
          {
              using (StreamReader reader =
                new StreamReader(gzip, System.Text.Encoding.UTF8))
              {
                  return reader.ReadToEnd();
              }
          }
      }
  }
  ```

**Got the error:**

> Block length does not match with its complement...

I sent a mail to the guys that are sending this XML data to my customer, but the problem is that they are very slow to respond (3-4 weeks).

So I am hoping someone can point me in the right direction.

I can not append files to the question, so if someone wants have a look at it I can send a mail or something?

Comment: Did you try rewriting the third way with `GZipStream`?

Comment: @JoachimIsaksson: I did look at the UnZipStr function

Comment: @dasblinkenlight: Do not know what you mean

Comment: Could you show the first few bytes of the file the first option writes to disk? Preferably in hex.

Comment: I mean using gzipstream in place of deflaterstream?

Comment: Try to use a library such as SharpZipLib of SharpCompress. Directly reading with a `DeflateStream` or `GZipStream` won't work if it's a real zip file, since it will have additional headers describing the contained files.

Comment: @JoachimIsaksson: Would be: PK䭐Ѓ㶢䄇 (copy/paste) Notepad++ shows it as some: DC4 BS caracters

Comment: @dasblinkenlight I tryed in the DecompressString function

Comment: This is all wrong. The result of base64 decoding is *not* a string, and you shouldn't pretend that it is. Also, you're now decoding from base64 *twice*.

Comment: @harold: When using functions DecompressString and UnZipStr I passed in the base64 encoded string.

Comment: @JulienLebosquain: Trying your suggestion will get back with the results

Comment: Ok then it's a little less wrong, but the result of un-base64-ing is still not a string and should not be decoded as though it was unicode (which it isn't, it's a zip file).

Comment: Figured it out thanks to Joachim but will post the Answer a bit later basicly it is a PKzip file converted to a string and then converted to a base64 string. So Approch 1 Initialy was right just saved the file in UTF8 but seems like ASCII works. Will put the answer a bit later when I have time.

Comment: Even though it works, I'm not at all convinced that it's actually correct. The data is supposed to be a base64-encoded ZIP-file, right? Not a base64-encoded "ZIP-file that is plain text", because that doesn't exist. Just save the bytes as bytes, which is what they are.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As Harold already pointed out in the comments, this is all wrong. In your last comment (Jester) you clarified that the zip file was first converted to a string, and then that string got converted to a base64 string. As this absolutely makes no sense (why should you do that), I imagine that you got something wrong there and really *mean* that the file got converted to a base64 string. This is best practice for email for example, and I've recently been doing that to transfer files via XML in XMPP. My guess would be that...

```
byte[] file = System.Convert.FromBase64String(encodedData);
File.WriteAllBytes(directoryToWriteTo+filename+".zip", file);
```

... creates the file you're looking for. byte[] here already IS a zip file. As zip files can be messy to deal with (as you didn't really say what's in there), I would recommend saving these bytes to a file and try to open it with a zip-software like WinRar. If this worked and you can get the file contents out of the zip file, you could ask another question how to the the contents. I would also recommend using SharpZipLib.dll, because it's really the only solution I got working in reasonable time so far.

Comment: yes this aproach was right I just wrote the concept wrong basicly it is FILE->BASE64->xml => BACK